# Apache Lucene: Creating an index between strings and doing intelligent searching

Tags: lucene

My problem is as follows: Let's say I have three files. A, B, and C. Each of these files contains 100-150M strings (one per line). Each string is in the format of a hierarchical path like /e/d/f. For example:

```
File A (RTL):
/arbiter/par0/unit1/sigA
/arbiter/par0/unit1/sigB
...
/arbiter/par0/unit2/sigA

File B (SCH)
/arbiter_sch/par0/unit1/sigA
/arbiter_sch/par0/unit1/sigB
...
/arbiter_sch/par0/unit2/sigA

File C (Layout)
/top/arbiter/par0/unit1/sigA
/top/arbiter/par0/unit1/sigB
...
/top/arbiter/par0/unit2/sigA
```

We can think of file A corresponding to circuit signals in a hardware modeling language. File B corresponding to circuit signals in a schematic netlist. File C corresponding to circuit signals in a layout (for manufacturing).

Now a signal will have a mapping between File A <-> File B <-> File C. For example in this case, /arbiter/par0/unit1/sigA == /arbiter_sch/par0/unit1/sigA == /top/arbiter/par0/unit1/sigA. Of course, this association (equivalence) is established by me, and I don't expect the matcher to figure this out for me.

Now say, I give '/arbiter/par0/unit1/sigA'. In this case, the matcher should return a direct match from file A since it is found. For file B/C a direct match is not possible. So it should return the best possible matches (i.e., edit distance?) So in this example, it can give /arbiter_sch/par0/unit1/sigA from file B and /top/arbiter/par0/unit1/sigA from file C.

Instead of giving a full string search, I could also give something like *par0*unit1*sigA and it should give me all the possible matches from fileA/B/C.

I am looking for solutions, and came across Apache Lucene. However, I am not totally sure if this would work. I am going through the docs to get some idea.

My main requirements are the following:

1. There will be 3 text files with full path to signals. (I can adjust the format to make it more compact if it helps building the indexer more quickly).
2. Building the index should be fairly fast (take a couple of hours). The files above are static (no modifications).
3. Searching should be comprehensive. It is OK if it takes ~1s / search but the matching should support direct match, regex match, and edit distance matching. The main challenge is each file can have 100-150 million signals.

Can someone tell me if such a use case can be easily addressed by Lucene? What would be the correct way to go about building a index and doing quick/fast searching? I would like to write some proof-of-concept code and test the performance. Thanks.

Comment: can you give examples like what you wanna search for and what would be the expected searchresult?

Comment: and for proper understanding: a/b/c has nothing to do with A,B and C right?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've rephrased the original post to give better clarity. Hope this helps.

Comment: so this files will be indexed once? and after that you like to search stuff? no reindexing or adhoc indexing because of changes on the files?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The files will be indexed only once. The content is static. It cannot change once it is frozen.

Comment: can you say how big this files are? in MB?

Comment: I would say each file would be about 1-2 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think based on your requirements the best solution would be a PoC with a given test set of entries. Based on this it should be possible to evaluate the target indexing time you like to achieve. Because you only use static informations it's easier, because do don't have to care about topics like NRT (near-real-time searches).

Personally i never used lucene for such a big information set but i think lucene is able to handle this.

How i would do it:

> - Read tutorials and best practices about lucene, indexing, searching and understand how it works
> - Define an data set for indexing lets say 1000 lines for each file
> - Define your lucene document structure
>
> this is really important because based on this you will apply your
>   searches. take care about analyzer tasks like tokanization if needed
>   and how. If you need fulltext search care about a TextField.
>
> - Write code for simple indexing
>
> Run small tests with indexing and inspect your index with [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke)
>
> - Write code for simple searching
>
> Define queries and your expected results. execute searches and check
>   results.

Try to structure your code. separate indexing and searching -> it will be easier to refactor.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: sure. if you face any problem just drop a comment and we can talk about that maybe on chat.